# The supplied phased action failed with an exception. problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.nassert localPropertiesFile.exists()

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm learning to import packages into my visual studio but suddenly an error like this appears,[image]

Is there any suggestion on what I can do to overcome such an error?
Any suggestions you have will be very valuable for me to study better, thank you

I hope someone helps me find a way to solve this error, because I'm very confused because I'm studying alone